# object is not defined error when running Jasmine tests on CoffeeScript files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I've been learning coffeescript, and as an exercise in learning it I've decided to TDD [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).  The first test I've chosen is to create a Cell and see if it's dead or alive.  To that end, I've created the following coffeescript:

```
class Cell 
  @isAlive = false


  constructor: (isAlive) ->
    @isAlive = isAlive
  
  die: ->
    @isAlive = false
```

I then am creating a Jasmine test file using the following code (it's a failing test on purpose):

```
Cell = require '../conway'

describe 'conway', ->
  alive = Cell.isAlive
  cell = null

  beforeEach ->
    cell = new Cell()

 describe '#die', ->
   it 'kills cell', ->
     expect(cell.isAlive).toBeTruthy()
```

However, when I run the tests in Jasmine, I get the following error:

```
cell is not defined
```

And the stack trace:

```
1) kills cell
   Message:
     ReferenceError: cell is not defined
   Stacktrace:
     ReferenceError: cell is not defined
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/gjstocker/cscript/spec/Conway.spec.coffee:17:21)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/jasmine-2.0.0.rc1.js:1001:15)
```

When I execute `coffee -c ./spec/Conway.spec.coffee` and look at the resulting JavaScript file, I see the following (Line 17, column 21 being the error):

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function() {
  var Cell;

  Cell = require('../conway');

  describe('conway', function() {
    var alive, cell;
    alive = Cell.isAlive;
    cell = null;
    return beforeEach(function() {
      return cell = new Cell();
    });
  });

  describe('#die', function() {
    return it('kills cell', function() {
      return expect(cell.isAlive).toBeTruthy(); //Error
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

My issue is that as far as I can tell, `cell` *is* defined.  I know I'm wrong (since [`SELECT is not broken`](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229002206/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2007/06/27/select-isnt-broken-or-horses-not-zebras/)), but I'm trying to figure out where I've messed up.  How do I diagnose this error with coffescript and figure out where I went wrong?

I've studied the source code contained in many coffeescript apps, including [this one](https://github.com/spaghetticode/game-of-life-coffeescript), but the source code is formatted exactly the same, with the declarations the same.

Answer (score 5):

It's an indenting issue, and [here's your fix](https://gist.github.com/3399818):

```
Cell = require '../conway'

describe 'conway', ->
  alive = Cell.isAlive
  cell = null

  beforeEach ->
    cell = new Cell()

  describe '#die', ->
    it 'kills cell', ->
      expect(cell.isAlive).toBeTruthy()
```

If you look at the compiled JavaScript, you have a `describe` block and there's a `beforeEach` inside of it. But your next `describe` block (which you *wanted* to be inside the first one) is *not* actually inside of it -- it's outside.

This is because the indenting on the second `describe` is only one space, not two.